# Can not rename the table's column name using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter

I am new in jupyter notebook and python. Recently I'm working in this code but I can't find out the problem. I want to rename `"Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $)" and "Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $).1"`  into `"Data" and "Revenue"` but it not changed. Here is my code:

```
!pip install pandas
!pip install requests
!pip install bs4
!pip install -U yfinance pandas 
!pip install plotly
!pip install html5lib
!pip install lxml
```

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
```

```
url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDeveloperSkillsNetworkPY0220ENSkillsNetwork23455606-2022-01-01"
html_data  = requests.get(url).text
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html5lib')
tesla_revenue = pd.read_html(url, match = "Tesla Quarterly Revenue")[0]
tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.rename(columns={"Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $)":"Date","Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $).1":"Revenue"})
tesla_revenue.head()
```

Here is the Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the error. You have a mistake in your column names. Instead of "Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $)" it is "Tesla Quarterly Revenue (Millions of US $)" with a space between Revenue and the value in brackets. The same applies to the second column header.

To avoid this you could also save the column names into a variable like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html5lib')
tesla_revenue = pd.read_html(url, match="Tesla Quarterly Revenue")[0]
col1_name = tesla_revenue.columns[0]
col2_name = tesla_revenue.columns[1]
tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.rename(columns={col1_name:"Date",col2_name:"Revenue"})
tesla_revenue.head()
```

This makes the code also a bit more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce the issue, it works as expected. May print your originally `.columns` and compare the values to your `dict` - Not sure if the source is interpreted differnt by module versions:

```
print(tesla_revenue.columns)
```

Just in case an alternative:

```
tesla_revenue.columns = ['Date','Revenue']
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue?utm_medium=Exinfluencer&utm_source=Exinfluencer&utm_content=000026UJ&utm_term=10006555&utm_id=NA-SkillsNetwork-Channel-SkillsNetworkCoursesIBMDeveloperSkillsNetworkPY0220ENSkillsNetwork23455606-2022-01-01"
tesla_revenue = pd.read_html(url, match = "Tesla Quarterly Revenue")[0]
#tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.rename(columns={"Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $)":"Date","Tesla Quarterly Revenue(Millions of US $).1":"Revenue"})
tesla_revenue.columns = ['Date','Revenue']
tesla_revenue.head()
```

##### Output

|  | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-09-30 | $21,454 |
| 1 | 2022-06-30 | $16,934 |
| 2 | 2022-03-31 | $18,756 |
| 3 | 2021-12-31 | $17,719 |
| 4 | 2021-09-30 | $13,757 |